# How to use a module-relative path to translations in .info.yml

Tags: i18n-l10n, configuration, .info

I'm new to using Drupal and am building a custom module to learn how it all works.

I'm building my module in `modules/custom/my_module`. I have a Dutch locale file in `modules/custom/my_module/translations/my_module-0.1.nl.po`.

If I specify it like that in my `.info.yml` file, it works great:

```
name: My Module
description: Just testing
version: 0.1
package: Custom
type: module
core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9
'interface translation project': my_module
'interface translation server pattern: modules/custom/my_module/translations/%project-%version.%language.po
```

But, now my `.info.yml` file would force users to install this module in `modules/custom/my_module`. I don't want that. I don't care where they put it. They can put this module in `modules/contrib/my_module` or `sites/all/modules/my_module` for all I care. Maybe someone will include it as a packaged dependency and it will end up in `modules/custom/some_module/modules/my_module`. It shouldn't matter and I don't want to hard-code the module path in my `.info.yml`.

What I *want* is to have my `.info.yml` file specify the server pattern using a module-relative path (relative to where my module's `.info.yml` file lives) like this:

```
'interface translation server pattern': translations/%project-%version.%language.po
# or perhaps as:                        ./translations/%project-%version.%language.po
```

But Drupal doesn't like this and checking for updates to translations will indicate the file could not be found.

I'm aware of the `translations://` and `public://` stream wrappers, but as far as I can tell this either requires the translation file to be hosted elsewhere, copied to the `sites/default/files` folder (which I could probably do in `my_module_install()` but is unhandy during development when I'm constantly adding strings) or (again) hardcoding the path to the module.

For now I've implemented the `hook_locale_translation_projects_alter()` hook in my `my_module.module` file to set an absolute path like this:

```
function my_module_locale_translation_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  $projects['my_module']['info']['interface translation server pattern'] =
    __DIR__ . '/translations/%project-%version.%language.po';
}
```

This works, but it feels like a nasty workaround and not how Drupal is intended to work.

What is the usual method to get module-relative paths to work for translations?

---

**Edit**: As suggested by @leymannx, instead of using `__DIR__` in my hook, I can use:

```
function my_module_locale_translation_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  $projects['my_module']['info']['interface translation server pattern'] =
    drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/translations/%project-%version.%language.po';
}
```

This feels slightly better, but I still feel this should be possible without implementing a hook for this.

Comment: Try `drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/translations/%language.po'`.

Comment: @leymannx can I do that in my yaml file? Or would I still need to implement the hook to use that function?

Comment: No, from the hook. I don't think you can have a module relative path in the info file. Only web-root relative.

Comment: @leymannx that works and feels better than using `__DIR__` but surely there's a way to do this from the yaml file without implementing the hook?

Comment: I don't think so. What's wrong with the hook?

Comment: The hook should not be necessary for something this trivial. It is also not executed when the module is not installed, so Drupal won't read the translated module name/description for the module list on the Extend page in the admin UI where I can select it and install it. (I actually haven't checked, but I *assume* it will read the translated name/description from the locale file specified in .info.yml for that page...)